# How do I persist a list of objects using jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, persistence, pickle, dill

I'm working on Jupyter and trying to make my list persistent but pickling just gives me this error:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3ba985598f1e> in <module>
      1 with open("book_data/books.pkl", "wb") as cf:
----> 2    pickle.dump(book_list, cf)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.book'>: it's not the same object as __main__.book
```

I tried using dill to save the session instead and it gave me this error:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5011bc09ef45> in <module>
      1 import dill
----> 2 dill.dump_session('Data_Gathering.db')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `dill` author.  If you are only looking to pickle a list of objects, you might just try

```
with open("book_data/books.pkl", "wb") as cf:
    dill.dump(book_list, cf)
```

`dill` can pickle the entire session, but from within a jupiter notebook it has some difficulty, so it's generally just easier to pickle the objects you are interested in.